# App stopped running on device - ‘No such file or directory'

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, xcode4.5

*Initially I started building an iPhone app (App still in development stage) using **Xcode 4.2**, it was working fine on both device and simulator.Later, we wanted to add support for **iPhone 5** (4 inch display). When I ran it on **Xcode 4.5** (including Default-568h.png), it was working fine (on the simulator both 3.5 inch and 4 inch). But when i tried to run it on device, it keeps on giving me the error*

`"Could not launch appname.app” No such file or directory (/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ffotpypmbvaguyhfvnnejhjotpbp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appname.app/appname).`

*I tried the following steps, but no luck :(*

- Deleted the app from device. Restarted the device.
- Quit XCode.Trashed all folders from `DerivedData.Cleaned the project. Restarted
  machine.
- Set `Build for active architecture`to YES
- Deleted `Required device capabilities` from -info.plist

*Do I have any other options to try, or should I repeat these again and again?*

Comment: I've had this too. Frustrating. Have you also fixed all warnings?

Comment: @skinnyTOD Yep.. No warnings :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last time I had a similar issue, a normal clean wasn't enough, as it left some derived data. In Xcode, select the Product menu and hold down the option key to reveal "Clean Build Folder...", or even better, close Xcode and delete `/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` entirely.

Comment: Command+Alt+Shift+k cleans up the entire project(Same as you have mentioned). I restarted my machine another time, and now I could run it using Xcode 4.2.. Still struggling on Xcode 4.5 :(